# Returning FREArray from Java to Flash

Tags: java, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

I have a native android function that I'm calling in Flash using an ANE:

```
public class GetProductsFunction implements FREFunction {
    private static final String TAG = "GetProducts";

    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
        FREArray freArray = IAPManager.getInstance().getFREProducts();

        return freArray;
    }
}
```

On the flash side I'm calling the function as so:

```
var object:Object = this.extContext.call("GetProductsFunction");
```

I'm not quite sure how to get at my FREArray that I returned. The function in Flash returns an ActionScript Object but you obviously can't get an Array from an Object.

So how do you read this data?

Comment: If you're working with AIR, FREArray is a native object.  See Adobe's FREArray Reference (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS982b6f491d178e6d6565d9b1132a79a012f-7ff8.html) for implementation.

Secondly, you're doing an implicit coercion of your FREArray to Object (which most everything inherits from).  Datatype your return variable as FREArray first, and the value won't be coerced.

Answer (score 1):

Java side:

```
public class testFunction implements FREFunction {
    public FREByteArray call(FREContext context, FREObject[] passedArgs) {    
        FREByteArray freByteArray = null;
        try {
            byte[] rdata = ...the bytes you have...;
            int packetLenght = 8;

            //Prepare an ActionScript ByteArray
            freByteArray = FREByteArray.newByteArray();
            freByteArray.setProperty("length", FREObject.newObject(packetLenght));
            freByteArray.acquire();
            ByteBuffer bytes = freByteArray.getBytes();

            //Fill it
            if(rdata != null)
                bytes.put(rdata, 0, packetLenght );

            freByteArray.release();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MYANE", "testFunction Exception " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return freByteArray;
    }
}
```

ActionScript side:

```
var rdata:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var received:Object = extContext.call('test') as ByteArray;
if (received is ByteArray)
{
    //Read bytes in rdata
    received.readBytes(rdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FREObject stringElement = FREObject.newObject("String element value"); 
FREArray asVector = FREArray.newArray( "String", 1, false ); 
asVector.setObjectAt( 0, stringElement );
```

More info
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS982b6f491d178e6d6565d9b1132a79a012f-7ff8.html